# How to add item to list in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and here is my problem:

```
data: {
        ws: null, 
        newMsg: '',
        username: null,    
        usersList: '' 
    },
        created: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/room');
        this.ws.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
                if (msg.Message == "joined" ) {
                self.usersList.push(msg.Name); // <--Problem here 
              }


        });
    },
```

But I get this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: self.usersList.push is not a function
```

I've also tryied a fixed string instead of `msg.Name` but get the same error.

What's wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: You declared as string `usersList: ''` in data, change it to `usersList: []`.

Comment: @MatJ Right. Just figured out! Please answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Use `userList:[]` as array, that you can use the `push()` method, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

2.When your `e.data` is a array, like: `[1,2,3,4]`, you can use `concat` to combine two array.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [5,6,7];
var arr = arr1.concat(arr2); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Or, `Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2);` to  push all elements from a second array.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [5,6,7];
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
console.log(arr1);//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```